# How to use `blur` and `change` the same time : jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to my `autosave` function ([link here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46152759/1620626)). Which is triggered by something change to the element. In this case `blur` and `change` - input text and checkbox.

I want to make the function working on both `typing` and `clicking` the box. Because there're both element type in the same line.

I tried `$('xxx').on('blur change',function()...`

But only change is working. Any idea???

Comment: Note that `change` only fires on `blur`, so they're behaviourally almost the same thing. Perhaps you should try the `input` event if you want to fire the event when the user types too

Comment: Wilf, was the answer helpful? Please respond

Answer (score 1):

You can use this type of pattern. And define a new function `commonFunction` that contains common code for both the events.

```
$("xxx").on({
    blur: function() {
        // Handle blur...
        commonFunction();
    },
    change: function() {
        // Handle change...
        commonFunction();
    }
});
```